# INR currency format in AngularJs in input type = text fields

Tags: html, angularjs

How to display number in INR format in textbox (input type=text).
So when user keeps changing the text it should accordingly format to INR format.

Below code works if we bind ng-model.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('indexCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.amount = 12564252.33;
});

app.filter('INR', function () {        
    return function (input) {
        if (! isNaN(input)) {
        
            var result = input.toString().split('.');

            var lastThree = result[0].substring(result[0].length - 3);
            var otherNumbers = result[0].substring(0, result[0].length - 3);
            if (otherNumbers != '')
                lastThree = ',' + lastThree;
            var output = otherNumbers.replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + lastThree;
            
            if (result.length > 1) {
                output += "." + result[1];
            }            

            return output;
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="indexCtrl">
    Input: <input type="text" ng-model="amount">
    <h3>{{amount | INR}}</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

basically i want the input field itself should be comma separated as soon as user is typing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('indexCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.amount = 12564252.33;
});

app.filter('INR', function () {        
    return function (input) {
        if (! isNaN(input)) {
        
            var result = input.toString().split('.');

            var lastThree = result[0].substring(result[0].length - 3);
            var otherNumbers = result[0].substring(0, result[0].length - 3);
            if (otherNumbers != '')
                lastThree = ',' + lastThree;
            var output = otherNumbers.replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + lastThree;
            
            if (result.length > 1) {
                output += "." + result[1];
            }            

            return output;
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="indexCtrl">
    Input: <input type="text" ng-model="amount">
    <h3>{{ amount | currency : "RS : " }}</h3>
  OR
   <h3>{{ amount | currency : "₹ : " }}</h3>
 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: actually i am not looking for binding the ng-model i want the input field itself to contain the comma separated INR format.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want custom format on input box.

You can achieve that by regular expressions and ng-pattern. Is that what you want ?